# Azure Devops pipeline unable to connect to AKS cluster

Tags: azure-devops, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I am using an ARM service connection in Azure Devops to deploy a helm chart to AKS using a Devops pipeline below.

```
- stage: Dev_Deployment
  displayName: "Deploy to Dev"
  jobs:
  - job: Deploy_to_AKS
    displayName: "Build, scan, and push the Docker image"
    steps:
    - task: HelmDeploy@0
      inputs:
        connectionType: 'Azure Resource Manager'
        azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        azureResourceGroup: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
        kubernetesCluster: 'aks-cluster'
        useClusterAdmin: true
        namespace: 'dev'
        command: 'upgrade'
        chartType: 'Name'
        chartName: 'xxxx/xxxxxx'
        valueFile: 'devops/helmvalues.yaml'
        arguments: '--debug'
```

But when the pipeline tried to deploy to the cluster I get an error like below:

> 2021-09-23T06:06:33.2448376Z ##[section]Starting: HelmDeploy
> 2021-09-23T06:06:33.2461242Z
> ============================================================================== 2021-09-23T06:06:33.2461562Z Task         : Package and deploy Helm
> charts 2021-09-23T06:06:33.2461921Z Description  : Deploy, configure,
> update a Kubernetes cluster in Azure Container Service by running helm
> commands 2021-09-23T06:06:33.2462221Z Version      : 0.183.0
> 2021-09-23T06:06:33.2462445Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
> 2021-09-23T06:06:33.2462691Z Help         :
> https://aka.ms/azpipes-helm-tsg 2021-09-23T06:06:33.2462992Z
> ============================================================================== 2021-09-23T06:06:34.0152308Z [command]/usr/local/bin/helm upgrade
> --namespace dev --install --values /home/vsts/work/1/s/devops/helmvalues.yaml --wait --debug 20210923.3
> xxxxxxx 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3572124Z Error: Kubernetes cluster
> unreachable: Get "xxxxxxx": dial tcp: lookup xxxxxxx on xxxxxxx: no
> such host 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3585227Z helm.go:81: [debug] Get
> "xxxxxxx": dial tcp: lookup xxxxxxx on xxxxxxx: no such host
> 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3586699Z Kubernetes cluster unreachable
> 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3587230Z
> helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/kube.(*Client).IsReachable
> 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3587833Z  helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/kube/client.go:115
> 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3588341Z helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*History).Run
> 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3588862Z  helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action/history.go:48
> 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3589375Z main.newUpgradeCmd.func2
> 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3589878Z  helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/upgrade.go:93
> 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3590399Z github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
> 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3591896Z
> github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3/command.go:852
> 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3592781Z
> github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
> 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3611885Z
> github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3/command.go:960
> 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3614477Z github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
> 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3616752Z
> github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3/command.go:897
> 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3617159Z main.main 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3617522Z
> helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:80 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3617900Z
> runtime.main 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3618254Z     runtime/proc.go:225
> 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3618598Z runtime.goexit
> 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3618966Z  runtime/asm_amd64.s:1371
> 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3676299Z ##[error]Error: Kubernetes cluster
> unreachable: Get "xxxxxxx": dial tcp: lookup xxxxxxx on xxxxxxx: no
> such host helm.go:81: [debug] Get "xxxxxxx": dial tcp: lookup xxxxxxx
> on xxxxxxx: no such host Kubernetes cluster unreachable
> helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/kube.(*Client).IsReachable
> helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/kube/client.go:115
> helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*History).Run
> helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action/history.go:48 main.newUpgradeCmd.func2
> helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/upgrade.go:93
> github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
> github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3/command.go:852
> github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
> github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3/command.go:960
> github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
> github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3/command.go:897 main.main
> helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:80 runtime.main    runtime/proc.go:225
> runtime.goexit    runtime/asm_amd64.s:1371
>
> 2021-09-23T06:06:38.3696886Z ##[section]Finishing: HelmDeploy

How do I fix this issue?
Edit: Updated the error

Comment: could you enable diagnostic settings and see if you can get more detailed error ?

Comment: @Thomas Updated the error in detail.

Comment: can you run the same command from your local machine ? how is our aks cluster networking configured ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I spoke to Azure about it. Looks like the Devops agents dont have access to our cluster.

We will need to set up another agent which will be in the same Vnet as the cluster and have access to AKS and the Azure Pipelines.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#im-running-a-firewall-and-my-code-is-in-azure-repos-what-urls-does-the-agent-need-to-communicate-with

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-configure-the-agent-to-bypass-a-web-proxy-and-connect-to-azure-pipelines

Comment: Glad to know that this issue has been resolved. I suggest that you can accept this answer. This will be helpful to other users.